# Reading binary data into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, xmlhttprequest, file-format

I've got a `WebGL` application which requires me to load a lot of `x,y` vertex data, but to minimise bandwidth usage I want to also compress the data (on a one off basis) using `gzip`.

Below is the code I will use to load in the data. I want to retrieve data from a server and pass it straight into a `Float32Array`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'array.gz', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(data) {
    console.log("loaded");
    var dataArray = new Float32Array(this.response);

xhr.onprogress = function(e) {
};
xhr.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('error!');
};
xhr.send();
```

Now my problem isn't linked to the code directly, but to the file format supported. In what format (i.e. `csv`, `json`, `xml`) does the data need to be in, before being gzipped so that this method can properly consume it?

I've played around to find that if I `JSON.stringify` a `Float32Array` and place the content in a file, then load it in, it works fine. However, to load in all my uncompressed data into a JavaScript array, before copying all its contents back into a new file to be compressed isn't very feasible. So I'm really looking for an alternative way to this (*assuming this file format is the only one supported*).